# how callback works between two classes?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm doing a course and trying to understand how a callback works between two classes. I prepared this example:

```js
    function Car() {

        this.offer = {};

        this.OfferUpdate = () => {
            this.callback(this.offer)
        }

        this.callback = function(){};

        this.Listener = (callback) => {
            this.callback = callback;
        }
    }

    var car = new Car();
    car.offer = {
        model: ['A4', 'A5', 'A6'],
        engine: ['TDI', 'TFSI']
    }

    class Car_showroom {

        constructor() {
            this.model = ['A4'];
            this.engine = ['TDI'];
 
            car.Listener((newItems) => {
                this.model = newItems.model
                this.engine = newItems.engine
            })
        }
    }

let car_showroom = new Car_showroom();
    
let p = document.createElement("p")
let p2 = document.createElement("p")
let text = document.createTextNode("car.offer: " + JSON.stringify(car.offer));
let text2 = document.createTextNode("car_showroom: " + JSON.stringify(car_showroom))
p.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(p);
p2.appendChild(text2);
document.body.appendChild(p2);

car.OfferUpdate(); //run callback

let p3 = document.createElement("p")
let text3 = document.createTextNode("car_showroom after  car.OfferUpdate(): " + JSON.stringify(car_showroom))
p3.appendChild(text3);
document.body.appendChild(p3);
```

When the `car.OfferUpdate()` call is launched, the callback in this method is started, which launches the `listner()` method, but I do not understand how.

How does calling `this.callback(this.offer)` trigger the `listner()` method?

Comment: Why do you think that `Listener` gets launched rather callback, that was previously passed there?

Comment: Side note: While you can do what you like in your own code, the *overwhelming* convention in JavaScript is that only constructor functions are capitalized, and camelCase rather than underscores is used for word separation. So your `Car` is fine, `Car_showroom` would be `CarShowroom` (or `CarShowRoom`), `Listener` would be `listener`, `OfferUpdate` would be `offerUpdate`, ... Following the convention is important when sharing code with others, such as when asking for help. :-) But it's a good idea in any case.

Answer (score 1):

> How does calling `this.callback(this.offer)` trigger the `listner()` method?

This code calls `car.Listener`, passing a function into it:

```
car.Listener((newItems) => {
    this.model = newItems.model
    this.engine = newItems.engine
})
```

`car.Listener` does this:

```
this.callback = callback;
```

...saving that function reference in its `callback` property. That means that that car's `callback` is now a reference to the function that was passed into `car.Listener` (the arrow function above setting `model` and `engine`). So later, `this.callback(...)` calls that arrow function (not `Listener`).

It might help to make the distinction between the function we're passing in and the call to `car.Listener` clearer. This code:

```
car.Listener((newItems) => {
    this.model = newItems.model
    this.engine = newItems.engine
})
```

could be rewritten like this to make the distinction clearer:

```
// Create a callback we can give to `car`
const ourCallback = (newItems) => {
    this.model = newItems.model
    this.engine = newItems.engine
};
// Give that callback to `car`
car.Listener(ourCallback)
```

Comment: I understand that in
`this.callback` property save a reference to the callback function, so if `this.callback(this.offer)` is executed then also run method with referece in `this.Listener`?

Comment: @JanuszO: Don't get hung up on the word "reference." Any time you have an identifier for a function, it's a *binding* (a variable, parameter, object property, etc.) containing a reference to the function, because functions are objects. So just like `var a = {}; b = a;` means we have two ways of accessing that one object (through `a` and through `b`), `var a = function() { /*...*/ }; b = a;` means we have two ways of referencing that function (through `a` and through `b`). Since functions in JavaScript are objects, we can pass them around, just like objects.

Comment: thanks for the help, i thought a little and i already understand ;-)